# Python algorithm for prime numbers

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to filter off the prime numbers from 1 to 100 and here is the codes. However, it turns out that there are many numbers missed in the output.

```
def isnot_prime(x):
if x == 1:
    return True
if x == 2:
    return False
for i in range(2, int(x**0.5)+1):
    if x % i == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print filter(isnot_prime, range(1,101))
```

The output is [1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 82, 84, 86, 88, 90, 92, 94, 96, 98, 100].

There must be something wrong with the algorithm. How can I improve it?

Thank you.

Comment: What is missing? What do you expect? E.g: 15 or 21? Btw just make a look up table with all the primes you need, and check against it. It is simpler and faster, and tons of implementations lie around in the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your `for` to this:

```
for i in range(2, int(round(x**0.5 + 1))+1):
    if x % i == 0:
        return True
```

Remove the `else:` and remember that int(float) just takes the integral part (it does not round).

Also, keep in mind that there are faster algorithms to do this. For example the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a fast and simple algorithm.

Comment: Thank you so much! It'll print the number '3' if I keep the keyword 'round'. Finally I modified the code to this:
def isnot_prime(x):
    if x == 1:
        return True
    if x == 2:
        return False
    for i in range(2, int(x**0.5+1)+1):
        if x % i == 0:
            return True
    return False
    
print filter(isnot_prime, range(1,101))

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way :

```
print filter(lambda x: len(['' for y in range(2,x) if x%y==0])==0,range(1,101) )
```